# Cassandra startup failed with exception: Exception encountered during startup

Tags: cassandra

While starting cassandra I am getting below error:

```
INFO  15:31:15 Completed flushing /home/sandeep/bck_up/data/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/system-local-tmp-ka-15-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1446651072594, position=106127)
INFO  15:31:15 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
INFO  15:31:15 Netty using native Epoll event loop

ERROR 15:31:15 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.run(Server.java:171) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:117) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:492) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:575) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.run(Server.java:171)
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:117)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:492)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:575)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:651)
Exception encountered during startup: null
INFO  15:31:15 Announcing shutdown
INFO  15:31:15 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
INFO  15:31:17 Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  15:31:17 MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

++++++
Below is my config File:

```
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories: 
- /home/sandeep/bck_up/data/cassandra/data
# commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
commitlog_directory: /home/sandeep/bck_up/data/cassandra/commit_logs
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /home/sandeep/bck_up/data/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points.
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: localhost
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
#server_encryption_options:
#internode_encryption: none
#keystore: conf/.keystore
#keystore_password: cassandra
#truststore: conf/.truststore
#truststore_password: cassandra
# More advanced defaults below:
# protocol: TLS
# algorithm: SunX509
# store_type: JKS
# cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
# require_client_auth: false

# enable or disable client/server encryption.
client_encryption_options:
#enabled: false
#keystore: conf/.keystore
#keystore_password: cassandra
# require_client_auth: false
# Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
# truststore: conf/.truststore
# truststore_password: cassandra
# More advanced defaults below:
# protocol: TLS
# algorithm: SunX509
# store_type: JKS
# cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
```

++++

Can someone please help me out whats wrong with the setup. I've installed cassandra 2.1 on Fedora-16 64 bit. Java version is : java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: Could you enable the 'enabled' option under 'client_encryption_options' and see if that still fails please. As in: enabled: false rather than #enabled: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really odd place to get an NPE.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/Server.java#L163-L171

I'd suggest you open a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/

Comment: I've reported a BZ. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: If I'm reading the error correctly, it looks like @sandeep is using 2.1.11, not 2.1 HEAD, so the relevent line is https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.11/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/Server.java#L171

Comment: Ah good catch. Cassandra.yaml encryption options being invalid seem likely.